# Add list instance to page layout

Tags: list

I'm sorry if this has been answered in some other thread but i can't find it.

I have a page layout for my team site. I also have a list definition and a instance of the list that lists all my team sites. I want to add the list of team sites to my start page of the team sites. How do I do that? Is it possible and what is the best practice?

Sure, I could add the list from the GUI with the list definition, but I want to force the list to be on the page so that the user always sees it...

Answer (score 1):

Add a ListView webpart on your home screen which will show your teamsites. I think it may help you